# Lost on creating lists and calling back to variables

Tags: python

I'm currently in the process of trying to create a menu to select food items for a restaurant and have no idea how to get the menu to display correctly. My current very rough idea of how it should work looks like this:

```
name = int(input ('Welcome to Dinos Cupcakes, enter your name to continue  '))

cc_list = [
            ['1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)', 1, 3.50],
            ['2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)', 1, 2.25],
            ['3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each) ', 1, 4.05],
            ['4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)', 1, 1.99]]
print cc_list

while #Selection does not equal 1-4 repeat list

quantity = int(input('How many would you like to purchase of this variety  '))

new_quantity = quantity * #Dougnut selection



print (name, 'here is your receipt:'):
```

I'm looking to have the end print something like this:

> NAME here is your receipt:
>
> -------------------------------  # Chocolate-dipped Maple Puffs  -------------------------------
>
> Total cost: $
>
> Thank you, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without doing everything for you. The below should be enough to get you where you need. Remember your cc_list is effectively a list within a list. To reference the elements you'll need to reference the selection (1,2,3,4) and then the elements in the list (0,1,2).

This will let you extract the selection the user makes to get the string, and the price. With this, you should be able to figure out how to give them a total and format your output.

```
name = input('Welcome to Dinos Cupcakes, enter your name to continue  ')
cc_list = [
            ['1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)', 1, 3.50],
            ['2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)', 1, 2.25],
            ['3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each) ', 1, 4.05],
            ['4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)', 1, 1.99]]
print(cc_list)


selct = int(input("Enter a number"))

order = cc_list[selct+1][0]
cost =str(cc_list[selct+1][2])




print(name + " your stuff")
print("The total cost is " + cost)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this is a 'raw' one, please use python 3.x

```
name = input ('Welcome to Dinos Cupcakes, enter your name to continue  ')

cc_list = [
            ['1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)', 1, 3.50],
            ['2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)', 1, 2.25],
            ['3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each) ', 1, 4.05],
            ['4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)', 1, 1.99]]
print(cc_list)

selection = int(input("Please select 1-4"))
while selection not in [1,2,3,4]:
    selection = int(input("Please select 1-4"))

quantity = int(input('How many would you like to purchase of this variety  '))

total_cost = quantity * cc_list[selection][2]

print(f'{name}, here is your receipt:')
print(f'------------------------------- # {cc_list[selection][0]} -------------------------------')
print(f'Total cost: ${total_cost}')
print('Thank you, have a nice day!')
```

CMD output:

```
Welcome to Dinos Cupcakes, enter your name to continue  bill
[['1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)', 1, 3.5], ['2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)', 1, 2.25], ['3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each) ', 1, 4.05], ['4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)', 1, 1.99]]
Please select 1-41
How many would you like to purchase of this variety  1
bill, here is your receipt:
------------------------------- # 2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each) -------------------------------
Total cost: $2.25
Thank you, have a nice day!
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification of yours:

```
name = input ('Welcome to Dinos Cupcakes, enter your name to continue: ')

cc_list = [
            ['1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)', 1, 3.50],
            ['2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)', 1, 2.25],
            ['3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each) ', 1, 4.05],
            ['4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)', 1, 1.99]]
print(cc_list)

hm=0
while hm not in range(1,5): 
   hm = int(input('Hello {}, Which item (1-4) would you like:  '.format(name)))

quantity=0
while quantity not in range(1,100): 
   quantity = int(input('How many would you like to purchase of this variety:  '))

new_quantity = quantity * cc_list[hm-1][2]

print (name, 'here is your receipt: ', new_quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to achieve your goal.

```
cc_list = [
        ['1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)', 1, 3.50],
        ['2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)', 1, 2.25],
        ['3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each) ', 1, 4.05],
        ['4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)', 1, 1.99]]

name = input ('Welcome to Dinos Cupcakes, enter your name to continue: ')
print()

for item in cc_list:
    print(item)

print()
choice = int(input('Your choice: '))

while choice not in range(1, 5):
    choice = int(input('Your choice: '))

quantity = int(input('How many would you like to purchase of this variety: '))

prices = quantity * cc_list[choice-1][-1]

product_name = cc_list[choice-1][0]

print("\n")
print('{} here is your receipt:'.format(name))
print()
print('----------- # {} -----------'.format(product_name))
print()
print("Total cost: {} $".format(prices))
print()
print("Thank you, have a nice day!")
```

> **Output:**

```
Welcome to Dinos Cupcakes, enter your name to continue: Alexis

['1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)', 1, 3.5]
['2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)', 1, 2.25]
['3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each) ', 1, 4.05]
['4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)', 1, 1.99]

Your choice: 2
How many would you like to purchase of this variety: 3


Alexis here is your receipt:

----------- # 2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each) -----------

Total cost: 6.75 $

Thank you, have a nice day!
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one in python3.x

```
name = input ('Welcome to Dinos Cupcakes, enter your name to continue : ')

cc_list = [
            ['1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)', 1, 3.50],
            ['2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)', 1, 2.25],
            ['3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each) ', 1, 4.05],
            ['4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)', 1, 1.99]]

for x in range(len(cc_list)):
    print(cc_list[x])

selection = int(input("Please select 1-4 : "))
while selection not in [1,2,3,4]:
    selection = int(input("Please select 1-4 : "))
# array start from possition 0
selection = selection - 1

quantity = int(input('How many would you like to purchase of this variety : '))

total_cost = quantity * cc_list[selection][2]

print(f'{name}, here is your receipt : ')
print(f'------------------------------- # {cc_list[selection][0]} -------------------------------')
print(f'Total cost: ${total_cost}')
print('Thank you, have a nice day!')
```

Output

```
Welcome to Dinos Cupcakes, enter your name to continue : Tim
['1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)', 1, 3.5]
['2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)', 1, 2.25]
['3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each) ', 1, 4.05]
['4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)', 1, 1.99]
Please select 1-4 : 4
How many would you like to purchase of this variety : 10
Tim, here is your receipt :
------------------------------- # 4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99) -------------------------------
Total cost: $19.9
Thank you, have a nice day!
```